# RDFS subClassOf: Can a class be a subclass of itself?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I want to create an ontology where a concept can be a subclass of another concept.
For example: a concept called "Planting" with sub-concepts "Propagation" and "Germination".
So I defined a class named "Concept" using WebVOWL, but when I tried to create a returning relationship with an rdfs:subClassOf property, it gives me an error that a loop is not possible (domain == range).
Is this definition possible? and if it's not, how can I define a relationship to the same class? knowing that they're all of the class "Concept".
I want to do this because some concepts don't have sub-concepts, and others do, so I want to differentiate the concepts with sub-concepts from the others.

This is how the Concept class is defined in the .ttl file:

`:Concept rdf:type owl:Class;  rdfs:label "Concept"@en .`

Thank you for help.

Comment: " but when I tried to create a returning relationship with an rdfs:subClassOf property, it gives me an error that a loop is not possible (domain == range)" - that sounds more like a tool limitation. An RDF class hierarchy can have cycles and semantically, any class is trivially a subclass of itself.

Comment: the question is now, what are your classes? Do you really only have a class `Concept`? And what you call sub-concept are then instances of the class `Concept`? By the way, did you have a look at SKOS?

Comment: I want to expand the ontology with other classes later, like Tools and Services, but for now Concept is the most important. I'm actually new to the ontology thing. Thank you for mentioning the SKOS, I see there are several properties I can use like the hasTopConcept instead of subClassOf. So the question now is: can an ontology consists of standard classes like SKOS with user-defined classes?